# Flutter ListView: widgets doesn't update

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview, statefulwidget, flutter-state

I have a listview that shows some items, inside a StatefulWidget :

```
  ListView.separated(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return RowItem(
              item: rowsList[index],
              index: index,
          );
      },
      separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Divider(
              height: 20,
              color: Colors.transparent,
          );
      },
      itemCount: rowsList.length,
  ),
```

RowItem is a StatefulWidget too.

Everithing works fine when i add and remove items from rowsList, but i'm facing problems when i try to update an existing RowItem. This is my function for update:

```
  void updateRow(int rowIndex, MyItem item) {
    setState(() {
       rowsList[rowIndex] = item;
    });
  }
```

but i still see inside listview the old values for updated item. (MyItem is an object that extends Equatable).

What's wrong?

Comment: Try using [keys](https://medium.com/flutter/keys-what-are-they-good-for-13cb51742e7d).

Comment: thank you, i just miss to set key to RowItem -.-

Comment: Does it solve your issue? If so, I'm reposting my comment as an actual answer.

Comment: sure, repost the answer and i'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

try `RowItem` widget try this

var item;

```
 @override
   void initState() {
    item = widget.item;
      super.initState();
    }
@override
  void didUpdateWidget(covariant SleepDeckStepper oldWidget) {
    item = widget.item;
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
  }
```

problem is `item` parameter is not updating for `RowItem`

Answer (score 0):

Reposting my comment. You should use a [Key](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/Key-class.html) on each `RowItem`.

More on them from Emily Fortuna [here](https://medium.com/flutter/keys-what-are-they-good-for-13cb51742e7d).